# Find what bundle a function was called from automatically

Tags: swift, bundle, xcasset

A project I'm working on was recently split into multiple smaller projects for reasons outside of my control.

We have some helper methods in one project to create shorthand and type safe image requests... The reason for this is to have flexibility around theming. Maybe one themes detailDisclosure isn't the same as anothers.

The syntax looks like this

```
public extension UIImageView {
    convenience init(_ key: UIImage.Key) {
        self.init(image: UIImage(named: theme.imageName(for: key)))
    }
}
```

`let imageView = UIImageView(.detailDisclosure)`

and it's sister function

`let image = UIImage(.detailDisclosure)`

Pretty simple stuff when all of the images and themes live in the same place. However now we have different projects, which have different assets inside different asset folders.

So what I had to add to make this work was this...

```
convenience init(_ key: UIImage.Key, in locality: AnyClass? = nil) {
    self.init(image: UIImageView.localImage(named: key.rawValue, in: locality))
}

// Currently assumes this method and default assets are in the main bundle by default 
fileprivate static func localImage(named name: String, in locality: AnyClass?) -> UIImage? {
    let bundle = (locality != nil) ? Bundle(for: locality!) : Bundle.main
    return UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
}
```

`let image = UIImage(.detailDisclosure, in: ThisProjectTheme.self)`

`ThisProjectTheme` can actually be any class inside this bundle, and technically you can go to another bundle and share its resources in this way too.

From a consumer perspective though, this extra effort is something I'd be looking to avoid, and it's also pretty dangerous for newcomers in my opinion.

What would be better, would be unless the consumer of this API specifies a different `locality`, we find their locality for them automatically; instead of the current solution to go to the main bundle.

In the future most of these requests will come from projects that have their own assets.

I've seen for example
`file: String = #file`

`convenience init(_ key: UIImage.Key, file: String = #file, in locality: AnyClass? = nil)`

Means we can hack at it obviously, but I'm wondering if there's an elegant solution to get a sender or for that matter bundle without the consumer implicitly sending it to the function?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"what bundle a function was called from automatically"

As appealing as this might sound, you ***reallllly*** don't want that. The moment you find that copy/pasting some code from one project to another makes it behave differently, is the moment you'll lose your marbles.

Instead, I think this entire approach needs to be reworked. For one, `UIImage` seems to be the wrong point of abstraction for this. Instead, I would use something like this:

```
import UIKit

class ImageProvider {
    let bundle: Bundle

    init(bundle: Bundle) {
        self.bundle = bundle
    }

    init(forMainClass mainClass: AnyClass) {
        self.init(bundle: Bundle(for: mainClass)!)
    }

    func image(
        named: String,
        with configuration: UIImage.Configuration? = nil
    ) -> UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: name, in: self.bundle, with: configuration)?
    }
}
```

Each app will create its own `ImageProvider`, which searches for assets within its own bundle.

This has several key advantages:

1. The interface can easily be extracted into a protocol, and a mock implementation can be created for use in tests.
2. You have a single point-of-entry into the image system, which allows you to handle caching, theming, sizing, etc.
3. You could extend this to handle look-up into multiple bundles ("first search my app bundle, if not, try this framework's bundle")
4. You could extend this to use an enum to identify images, rather than raw strings.

Comment: Yeah that's a really salient point, I think I'm going too far down the road of trying to guess for the sake of a simpler syntax. I think a separate class might be slightly too much for my implementation (which you haven't seen) when setting a theme I'll ask for the bundle that keeps your assets and that'll work perfectly. Thanks for the sanity.

Comment: "I think a separate class might be slightly too much for my implementation" why is a class too much?

Comment: I like the extension of `UIImage` as an api, and the providing / flexing will be done by the theme.. so depending on the theme we can look in a the bundle the consumer specifies.

Comment: @Magoo That doesn't really answer my question. Extending UIImage in this way is kind of a half-measure, IMO. There's a continuum. One one side, you have a position in which you don't use abstractions and just use raw APIs. It might not be the most succinct code, but everyone's seen it and is familiar with it. On the other hand, you abstract things to make them easier, but there's an initial learning curve. Extending UIImage lands you in the middle, with the draw backs of both sides and the benefits of neither